# jquery selector not working with brackets

Tags: json, jquery

I struggle to use a jquery selector containing brakcets.
Basically I parse a JSON response from the server in my jquery code. Then I iterate over the object, once the parsing is done.

This object has such a structure:

```
  errors = {
   input#title_id: "error message",
   select#authors_id[]: "error message 2"
  }
```

Then I iterate over this map like follow:

```
$.each(errors, function(fieldSelector,errMsg){
  fieldSelector = fieldSelector.replace('[','\\\\[');
  fieldSelector = fieldSelector.replace(']','\\\\]');
  $(fieldSelector).hide(); //for the example
}
```

Everything works well except for the select that has an id with brackets!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [jQuery Selector documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), you need to use two brackets to escape meta-characters:

> If you wish to use any of the meta-characters ( such as 
>    `!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^{|}~` ) as a literal part of a name, 
>    you must escape the character with two backslashes: `\\`. 
>    For example, if you have an element with `id="foo.bar"`, you can
>    use the selector `$("#foo\\.bar")`.

But the double brackets are only required so that a single bracket char `\` is present in the selector string. The selector engine then uses that bracket later on to escape the meta character. Anyway, this means that your code also only needs to use two brackets - there is no need to provide an extra level of escaping:

```
$.each(errors, function(fieldSelector,errMsg){
    fieldSelector = fieldSelector.replace('[','\\[');
    fieldSelector = fieldSelector.replace(']','\\]');
    $(fieldSelector).hide(); //for the example
});
```

Comment: do you mean defining it on the server side ? Because i receive `errors` after the json_encode function is called in a PHP script.

Comment: Yes but I thought it's what I did by using replace on `fieldSelector` isn't ?

Comment: @renard - Yes, but you provided an extra level of escaping. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly easier answer - you can use gEBI, which doesn't have special syntax, instead of Sizzle.

```
$.each(errors, function(fieldSelector,errMsg){
    $(document.getElementById(fieldSelector)).hide(); //for the example
}
```